# resources not linked into final APK

Tags: eclipse, proguard, android-resources, apk

I can run my app fine in the emulator and *with the same source* compile a final APK, but on another computer with exactly the same environment (Android-SDK, Eclipse and sources!) copied there, the project's resources are not compiled into the final APK when creating a distribution package.
As a consequence, the distribution APK is only 122k in size, while the correct size is supposed to be about 290k. It is displayed as "invalid" when trying to install it on a device.

Any idea why? It doesn't make a difference whether I'm using the original proguard file or an empty one.

Comment: Check `.project` file and ADT installation

Comment: My ADT installation is the "original" bundle provided by Google. The .project file just has this line activated: "target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:15" -- and Google API 15 is installed with the Android SDK setup. .. any other clue on what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I mean the file `.project` starting with a dot. It should look similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>MiniCallWidget</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
            <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
            <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: yes, it looks like that... o.O 
It must have something to do with the project's settings though, as the ADT/Eclipse installation is the original one as provided by Google.

Comment: In the final .APK, the subdirectory "res", AndroidManifest.xml and resources.arsc are missing.